# Regex to match a list of exact strings with some variable characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a way to match a list of parameters that include some predefined characters and some variable characters using Java's `String#matches` method. For instance:

Possible Parameter 1: `abc;[variable lowercase letters with maybe an underscore]`

Possible Parameter 2: `cde;[variable lowercase letters with maybe an underscore]`

Possible Parameter 3: `g;4`

Example 1: `abc;erga_sd,cde;dfgef,g;4`

Example 2: `g;4,abc;dsfaweg`

Example 3: `cde;df_ger`

Each of the parameters would be comma-separated but they can come in any order and include 1, 2, and/or 3 (no duplicates)

This is the regex I have so far that partially works:
`(abc;[a-z_,]+){0,1}|(cde;[a-z,]+){0,1}|(g;4,){0,1}`

The problem is that it also finds something like this valid: `abc;dsfg,dfvser` where the beginning of the string after the comma does not start with a valid `abc;` or `cde;` or `g;4`

Comment: Why do you think a regex is tool you want?

Answer (score 1):

As you said:

> The problem is that it also finds something like this valid:
> abc;dsfg,dfvser where the beginning of the string after the comma does
> not start with a valid abc; or cde; or g;4

Therefore the valid entries will always have the patterns after the comma. What you can do is, you can split the each inputs with the delimiter `","` and apply the valid regex pattern to the split elements and then combine the matching results of the split elements to get the matching result of the whole input line.

Your regex should be:

```
(abc;[a-z_]+)|(cde;[a-z_]+)|(g;4)
```

You'll get any of these three patterns just like you have mentioned in your post earlier, in a valid element which you've gotten by doing a split on the input line.

Here's the code:

```
String regex = "(abc;[a-z_]+)|(cde;[a-z_]+)|(g;4)";
boolean finalResult = true;
for (String input: inputList.split(",")) {
    finalResult = finalResult && Pattern.matches(regex,input);
}
System.out.println(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use matches, then the whole string has to match.

```
^(?:(?:abc|cde);[a-z_]+|g;4)(?:,(?:(?:abc|cde);[a-z_]+|g;4))*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:abc|cde);[a-z_]+` match either `abc;` or `cde;` and 1+ chars a-z or `_`
  - `|` Or
  - `g;4` Match literally
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,(?:(?:abc|cde);[a-z_]+|g;4)` Match a comma, and repeat the first pattern
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AKUaoS/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Jj6b1Q)

Example code

```
String[] strings = { 
        "abc;erga_sd,cde;dfgef,g;4",
        "g;4,abc;dsfaweg",
        "cde;df_ger",
        "g;4",
        "abc;dsfg,dfvser"
};

String regex = "^(?:(?:abc|cde);[a-z_]+|g;4)(?:,(?:(?:abc|cde);[a-z_]+|g;4))*$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

for (String s : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.printf("Match for %s%n", s);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("No match for %s%n", s);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Match for abc;erga_sd,cde;dfgef,g;4
Match for g;4,abc;dsfaweg
Match for cde;df_ger
Match for g;4
No match for abc;dsfg,dfvser
```

If there should not be any duplicate `abc;` `cde` or `g;4` you can rule that out using a negative lookahead with a backreference to match the same twice at the start of the pattern.

```
^(?!.*(abc;|cde;|g;4).*\1)(?:(?:abc|cde);[a-z_]+|g;4)(?:,(?:(?:abc|cde);[a-z_]+|g;4))*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tGeoYt/1)